# Hidden Markov Models inplementation in R or python

Tags: python, r, bioconductor, hidden-markov-models

Do you know any good literature and/or tutorials about how to implement HMM in python, R (Bioconductor)? (especially for sequence analysis)

Comment: Try asking on stats.stackexchange.com - or a mod can maybe move this q there.

Answer (score 5):

There is the HMM package on CRAN, which might be a good place to start.

http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/HMM/index.html

This is easily found from R itself:

```
RSiteSearch("HMM")
```

Answer (score 5):

GHMM for python has a [tutorial](http://ghmm.sourceforge.net/ghmm-python-tutorial.html), but it's short and they admit that "[Currently, the GHMM is utterly lacking in documentation.](http://ghmm.sourceforge.net/documentation.html)"

I like [the Rabiner paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf).

I have a technical report on [the use of HMM for genetic mapping](http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/publications/hmm.pdf).

I recommend reading a bit of Rabiner and then implementing something.  The forward/backward equations are just a few lines.